# C++ const char if-statement

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char, constants

So I'm trying to get this program that will say good or bad depending on your answer and I didn't want to have a really long if and else if statement with a bunch of strings so I put a bunch of possible answers in two chars and I want it to answer depending on what you say. The program only replies to the good answers saying good even if you enter in one of the bad answers.

```
const char* good[5] = {
    "good", "great", "amazing", "amazing!", "fantastic"
};

const char* bad[5] = {
    "bad", "bad pal", "bad eugene", "not good", "not good pal"
};

string input01 = "";

int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    cout << "How are you doing today?" << endl;
    cin >> input01;
    transform(input01.begin(), input01.end(), input01.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (input01 == good[0 > 5] || good[0 < 5]){
        system("CLS");
        cout << "good" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (input01 == bad[0 > 5] || bad[0 < 5]){
        system("CLS");
        cout << "bad" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: `input01 == good[0>5] || good[0<5]` wut? What did you want to mean with `0>5` and `0<5` there?

Comment: i wanted it to read if the word inputted into  the string related to the words in the spaces 0-5 in the char

Comment: So if input is one of the five `good` words, output good. if one of the five `bad` words, output bad and if neither output nothing?

Comment: That's just such a bad misconception of what array indices are doing :-(.

Comment: yes but it only outputs good no matter the answer

Comment: `good[0<5]` isn't valid C++ syntax. You need to iterate over all elements of both arrays to check for the input string. It seems that the expression `input01 == good[0>5] || good[0<5]` somehow evaluates to true.

Comment: @nitram: it is value syntax--see my answer for why/how it works.

Comment: Hrmmm programming by guessing, eh...

Comment: @JerryCoffin: OK, I stand corrected: It is valid syntax. But it's still nonsense, as you proved in a lot more words... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ((strcmp(input.c_str(), good[0]) == 0) ||
    (strcmp(input.c_str(), good[1]) == 0) ||
...
    (strcmp(input.c_str(), good[4]) == 0))
```

Or better switch the keywords to strings,

```
const string good[5] = {
    "good", "great", "amazing", "amazing!", "fantastic"
};
```

and then

```
if ((input == good[0]) ||
    (input == good[1]) ||
...
    (input == good[4]))
```

Or even better, pack the keywords into a set

```
const set<string> good{"good", "great", "amazing", "amazing!", "fantastic"};
```

and then

```
if (good.find(input) != good.end())
```

Comment: But there's a `operator==` overload in `std::string` that accepts a `const char*` so there's no need to either use `strcmp` or make the array a `std::string` itself. But the `std::set` is definitely a good solution.

Comment: Right right right. That's me falling back into C-thinking again. Part of why I'm hanging around here, trying to train myself out of that.

Answer (score 1):

This: `if (input01 == good[0 > 5] || good[0 < 5])` probably doesn't do what you expect (because I can't imagine wanting what it really does).

`0 > 5` is evaluated as a test of whether 0 is greater than 5. Since it's obviously not, that produces false. Since it's being used in a context where an integer is needed, that's converted to 0, so that part of the expression becomes `if (input01 == good[0]`.

Likewise, `0 < 5` tests whether 0 is less than 5 (which it obviously is) so the result is true, which converts to 1, so that part of the expression is `good[1]`. Since *that* in turn is being used as a Boolean expression, it's treated as equivalent to `good[1] != 0`.

So what you have overall is `if (input01 == good[0] || good[1] != 0)`.

That seems close enough to useless that I'm pretty sure it's not what you wanted. In particular, `good[1]` is a pointer. A pointer will compare equal to 0 if and only if it's a null pointer. Since it's initialized to point at something, it's not a null pointer, so that part of the expression will always evaluated as true.

of course, your other `if` statement is about equally useless.

If you want to check whether `input01` is equal to any of the items in `good`, you might (for one example) use `std::find`:

```
if (std::find(std::begin(good), std::end(good), input01) == std::end(good))
    // input01 was not present in `good`.
```

To make that work correctly, you'll want to use `std::string`s though:

```
std::vector<std::string> good{"good", "great", "amazing", "amazing!", "fantastic"};
```

It's kind of pointless for only 5 items, but if you lists of `good` and `bad` words are likely to get really large, you'd probably be better off sorting them, then using `std::binary_search`, or else using `std::unordered_set` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the input01 is in your array. You should be able to use the find() function to do this. Something like

```
if(std::find(std::begin(good), std::end(good), input01) != std::end(good))){do something}
```

You may not need the std:: references

Comment: Oooo! I  missed this one. Nice and simple